# Phillip Marlowe: How many films?

Tags: movie-franchise, noir

I recently attended a [24 Hour Film-Noir-A-Thon](http://www.cornerhouse.org/film/film-events/24-hour-noir-athon), which was brilliant (if not a little exhausting), and talking to some of the other patrons they were discussing the lack of Philip Marlowe movies, him being such an iconic figure of the genre...

One of the event organizers explained that, whilst they were showing *The Big Sleep*, Marlowe has far too many movie's and, notably, some of them are incredibly **Obscure**, so obscure that even she couldn't name them in anywhere near what she considered their entirety...

We discussed *Lady In The Lake*, which they are also showing as part of their film season, an also *The Long Goodbye* as some of the less recognized Marlowe films, but a few other people were convinced there were stranger and more remote ones.

Does anyone know what makes up the complete *Marlowe Collection*, including his non-hard-boiled iterations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philip_Marlowe), it appears there were only ten film adaptations of Chandler's detective. On the television, there was a three series, the first one in B&W in '59-60 on ABC, which aired 26 episodes. The second one was in color in '84 with only five episodes appeared on London Weekend Television. The third series was six episodes in Canada. That was in 1986. There were also many single movies/TV specials during that time and after. You can read all about the different exploits of Phillip Marlowe at [Thrilling Detective](http://www.thrillingdetective.com/marlow2.html) website, which also talks about Chandler's written works which movies/tv are based off of.

Comment: *There were also many single movies/TV specials during that time and after.* ... these are the ones I'm looking for! Apparently there is a 'Marlowe in space', and not the star trek reference either...

Comment: The website I posted has all of it there.